# Could we use only one ClassInitialize for all the Unit Testing classes?

Tags: c#, sql, unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

I started an internship  where my job consists of seting up unit tests on some projects.

I have already implemented dozens of tests and now I want to create a mechanism which restores the original database after or before each run.

I have the necessary scripts to create, populate and drop my database, but I don't want to call this mechanism each test classes, but instead call it just once.

Is it possible to create a `ClassIniatialize()` who is called only once when I start one or all the tests?

**EDIT**

All I/you need is to use ***AssemblyInitialize()*** and ***AssemblyCleanUp()*** and all is resolved, ;)

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, unit-testing should not depend on database calls. Instead, use some form of a mock to simulate predictable results when it comes to database access.

Comment: Don't write **solved** int the question title. You can accept the best answer and therefore show everybody it is solved.

Comment: But I wrote the "best answer" by giving me the précisions I needed...
What I have to do then ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All I/you need is to use ***AssemblyInitialize()*** and ***AssemblyCleanUp()*** and all is resolved, ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could start a transaction on `TestInitialize` and do a rollback on `TestCleanup`. This approach would allow you to avoid data changes to perdure outside the scope of individual tests.

```
  [TestInitialize()]
  public void Initialize()
  {
     //Init DB Transaction
  }

  [TestCleanup()]
  public void Cleanup()
  {
     //Rollback DB Transaction, database returns to the initial state
  }
```

You'll need to have a previously populated test database to run test on.

As a side note, database access should be tested on integration test and not on unit test. Adding external dependencies is against unit test definition.

Check also about the possibility of using in memory [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html), will be more suitable for testing database access that a production db engine.

Comment: @AndreiZubov: well, that's why, among other reasons, real database shouldn't be used on unit tests :)

Comment: It's the way I already setted up for my tests but the init takes too much time imo.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a base class and decorate a method in that base class with the ClassInitialize-attribute.

After that you just need to make sure that all your test-classes inherit from this base class.

Comment: I'm not sure to well understand.
I create a simple C# class with the parameters I need for all my tests (in my case the setting up of the database and the drop of the database) and I set all my test as inherited from this class ?

Answer (score 0):

ClassInitilize method will be called once for every testclass you have. You may implement it just once in a base testclass for example, but it will still be called once for every test class.

Comment: Hum... Then I will have to create, populate and drop all my tables at every run. It will take a long time for each run.
Or I could put all my tests in a same test class maybe.

Comment: Yes, it is. You may experiment with [Priority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.priorityattribute.aspx) attribute though. But it's not very good solution I suppose.